# Reorder data in Vim

Tags: vim, macros, rows

I have a hierarchical list, like this

```
Menu1,SubMen1.1,SubMen1.2,SubMen1.3
Menu2,SubMen2.1,SubMen2.2,SubMen2.3
Menu3,SubMen3.1,SubMen3.2,SubMen3.3
```

And i want to run a script or a macros that rearanges the info to this

```
Menu1,SubMen1.1
Menu1,SubMen1.2
Menu1,SubMen1.3
Menu2,SubMen2.1
Menu2,SubMen2.2
Menu2,SubMen2.3
...
```

Is there any way I can do this?

**EDIT:**

I should say that all rows have different lengths. Some have only one item, others have eight.

There are also around 4,000 of them in one file. I have about another 20 files to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [similar question on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/sjnre/i_need_help_reorganising_a_csv_filecan_it_be_done/) a few days ago, [the solution posted there by sylvain_soliman](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/sjnre/i_need_help_reorganising_a_csv_filecan_it_be_done/c4elewo) appears to work for this case as well.  I'm posting it here merely to show a different approach to the problem.

```
:%s/\(^\([^,]*\),.\+\)\@<=,/\r\2,/g
```

To make this a little more readable, use `\v`:

```
:%s/\v(^([^,]*),.+)@<=,/\r\2,/g
```

A little explaination:

- `:%s/` - replace over all lines in the buffer
- `\v` - use "very magic" regex syntax (prevents escaping things like parens)
- `(^([^,]*),.+)` - Matches a string at the beginning of a line, followed by a comma, followed by at least one character.  This places the string from the beginning of the line until the comma in matchgroup 2.
- `@<=` - tells vim to match the previous group with zero width, so it will not be replaced.
- `,` - matches the next comma.
- `/\r\2,/g` - replaces the comma from above with a newline and the string from matchgroup 2.

Comment: Beautiful! I was trying to find a one-line regex for this problem, but I couldn't get the nested matchgroups to work. This is a very instructive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use macro to do that, maybe not graceful, but works. (`<CR>` is `enter` key)

```
ggqqdw:s/,/\="\r".getreg('"').','/g<CR>jq
```

now you can use `@q` to repeat macros:

```
4000@q
```

at last, remove all temporary empty line

```
:g/^$/d
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain this!

Comment: I get most of it, but the problem I have is that some of the lengths are different. Like some menus have only two items, while others have 8.

Comment: @Ethan. Thanks. It works when i do it manually for each line. But when I do 400@q it tells me it's not a command.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you really press the `enter` key instead type "<CR>" to the vim cmd line?